# Copy and pasting text directly from Word is converted into an image: Bug or Cool New Feature?

Tags: discussion, bug, images

Very recently I discovered a new "trick". If I copy some text from a website onto Word and then copy and paste the text into a post, the editor prompts me to download it as an image. See below

An excerpt from *Macbeth* [[source](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/macbeth/full.html)]

[image]

Here is the same excerpt but following late 18th-century typography and spelling convention, the text has been modified. Note also the missing line from the previous version and the indention which I added. Alas, I failed in my quest to find the ct ligature character needed in the word “Function”.

[image]

and here's a joke, this is the [source](http://www.cc.com/feeds/transcripts/video/0ba2cd68-ed01-11e0-aca6-0026b9414f30)

[image]

Here I replaced the capital letters with lowercase, changed the font but left the formatting alone

[image]

Cool! *No?*

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320162/323179), although the questioner said Word pastes normally. I would consider this a bug since this isn’t desirable behavior. Some people draft their posts in Word but it does need to be text when posted for accessibility reasons.

Comment: @Laurel But there are also advantages to posting texts correctly formatted with special characters and fonts. I just spent an hour searching for the unicode for the ct ligature but with no success. https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Latin_small_ligature_Ct.svg

Comment: There is no reason why you can't provide transcribed text *as well as* an image. It's just having *only* an image that's a problem. This seems like a useful feature as something to add to an existing post.