# Copying text from OneNote and pasting creates an image instead of text

Tags: bug, images, posts, paste

Steps to reproduce:

- Write something in [OneNote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_OneNote)
- Copy that text
- Try pasting in Stack Overflow
- It opens the image upload dialog box (Example: [The image in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58132171/4993513))

PS: I tried pasting the same in the [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) editor, and it pasted the text properly.

OS Version: Windows 10

I tested and replicated it on the following two browsers:

- Chrome: Version 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Edge: Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0

Comment: Cross-site duplicate on Stackoverflow: [Copy/paste from Microsoft Word triggers image upload](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381951/7443472) Explanation from an employee: ["We are not going to be working on a fix for this at the time being. Seems that it is only happening with Word for Mac. And there is a good workaround in place as well" \[...\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381951/copy-paste-from-microsoft-word-triggers-image-upload#comment727104_381951)

Comment: Note that pasting as comment works fine and paste as text.

Comment: Microsoft has done a lot of fantastically stupid things in their time, but this has to rank among the most nonsensical. Who the f*xx wants a _picture_ of their text? Crackheads, all of them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As a simple workaround, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste, which will paste the clipboard contents as plain text. (Can also right click the editor and choose "Paste as plain text".)

VSCode editor, and other editors that don't accept images, are reading it as plain text always, but since Stack Exchange editor does accept images, it can't really know what you want to paste.

If you paste it into image editor, you'll also get the text as image. All in all, that's not SE fault. The bug, if there is any, is in OneNote itself, which should not put image inside the clipboard when you copy only text.

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively to Shadow's answer, you can use an intermediate program to paste and copy your text in. For example [WordPad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPad), or your OS's version of that.

Simply paste the copied content from OneNote into WordPad. 
Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select everything you pasted. 
Followed by <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

Finally post your content, which is now properly noted as text in your clipboard, into your answer or question.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to report that this issue is still occurring, and I believe that this is an issue unique to copying from OneNote.

Reporting this from:

Version 16001.14326.21090.0

I'd suggest anyone else having this problem to log a bug report with Microsoft.