# Paste tables from spreadsheet software directly as new table format

Tags: feature-request, markdown, tables

When I copy the specific Excel cells and paste them into a Stack Exchange post, the data is automatically treated as an image. It would be great if it is pasted as the [new table format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997).

OS   : Windows 10
Excel: Office 365 Version 1908

For example, after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, the following image is added:

[image: Excel Cells]

Instead, the following native HTML table should be generated:

| S/No | Item | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Product 1 | 10 |
| 2 | Product 2 | 15 |
| 3 | Product 3 | 30 |

Comment: Also consider upvoting https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357632/394472

Comment: This question should be reopened. The [linked "bug" report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320162/394472) has nothing to do with the latest table support, whereas this question is a feature request same as https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357632/394472 but as a separate question.

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann not duplicate, but looks like OP means only SO, which makes it off topic here.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating The question author seems to agree with the edit 8, suggesting he actually meant to enable this feature on all Stack sites where the table feature is available. There is no reason to restrict this feature to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 9):

While we wait for this feature to be implemented, here is a trick you can use from within Excel to convert the data into Markdown format:

In an empty cell to the right of the first row of the data, use this formula:

```
=CONCATENATE("|",TEXTJOIN("|",FALSE,A1:C1),"|")
```

Where A1 and C1 should be updated to reflect the starting column (and row) and ending column.

This will give you the markdown for a single row. Double click the little box at the bottom right corner of this cell to expand the formula to the end of the data. That should give you all of the data in Markdown format. You will just have to manually insert the row which separates the table heading from the body (i.e. `|---|---|---|`)

Comment: I'm not really experienced with excel so there might be an even better way of doing this without having to expand the formula (some kind of script perhaps?)

Comment: For Google sheets:[Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855).